# T-SQL stored procedure did not do anything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL stored procedures and am having difficulty getting one I grandfathered [from am existing SP that does work, written by another author] to execute properly. The following is intended to replace existing records in the 'Data' table with updated ones, and to append new records (both from the 'UpdateTemp' table, when updated).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessNewData]
AS

DECLARE @MaxDate varchar(10);
DECLARE @MinDate varchar(10);

SELECT @MaxDate = Max([Date]) FROM [dbo].[UpdateTemp];
SELECT @MinDate = Min([Date]) FROM [dbo].[UpdateTemp];

--Remove months from existing data that have updated data
DELETE
FROM [Data]
WHERE
([Type] = 'A' AND
([Date] = @MaxDate OR [Date] = @MinDate))
OR
([Type] = 'B' AND
([Date] = @MaxDate OR [Date] = @MinDate))

--Insert new data
EXEC('INSERT INTO [Data] SELECT * FROM [UpdateTemp];')

--Delete UpdateTemp table
EXEC('DROP TABLE [dbo].[UpdateTemp];')
```

There is another very similar SP written by someone else that did execute successfully. Which is below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[process_data]
AS

DECLARE @max_month varchar(10);
DECLARE @min_month varchar(10);
DECLARE @newTableName varchar(21);

SELECT @max_month = Max([month]) FROM [dbo].[Update_Temp];
SELECT @min_month = Min([month]) FROM [dbo].[Update_Temp];

SET @newTableName = 'Update_' + @max_month  


--Drop table if exists
EXEC('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].['+@newTableName+'];')

--Rename the database
EXEC sp_rename 'Update_Temp', @newTableName

--Remove 2 month from outcome
DELETE
FROM [Outcome]
WHERE
[month] = @max_month OR [month] = @min_month

--Insert new data
EXEC('INSERT INTO [Outcome] SELECT * FROM ['+@newTableName+'];')
```

The 'UpdateTemp' table was loaded successfully. I've tested the code by itself and it works. However it appears the SP did not run at all, or didn't do anything when it did.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Comment: First - post DDL for the tables involved. Next, start using best practices in your code - this "someone else" does not so that code should not be used as a pattern. Use statement terminators. Check for and throw errors when conditions merit. For example, what should happen when UpdateTemp is empty? Always specify a column list for an insert statement and for a select statement. Lastly - provide context. How do base your issue on "appears it did not run"?

Comment: And this logic `([Date] = @MaxDate OR [Date] = @MinDate))` seems faulty. Did you really intend to delete rows where [Date] is between (inclusive) these two values?

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Just wrapping object names in square brackets is not the same thing. You should also specify the column list fro `insert` and `select` to avoid surprises if a table definition is altered, e.g. the order of columns changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can run the commend without the `EXEC(    )`.
   Just do the insert and drop.
   The exec was for the dynamic code, where the table name is a variable. A different use case.
2. I recommend you use `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`.
   So when you implement to prod you have the correct code.
   For the same reason `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.
3. Start using `NOCOUNT ON`.
4. Finish up with `GO`.
   I love to test the proc after it is created - it enters the proc's code if no `GO` is in there.
5. There are no parameters - just run the code as is.
   If it works out of the SP it will inside it.
   When the SP receives parameters, you replace the `PROCEDURE` statement with a `DECLARE` and do the same.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessNewData]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @MaxDate varchar(10),
        @MinDate varchar(10);
    
SELECT @MaxDate = Max([Date]), @MinDate = Min([Date])
FROM [dbo].[UpdateTemp];
    
--Remove months from existing data that have updated data
DELETE
FROM [Data]
WHERE
([Type] = 'A' OR [Type] = 'B') AND
([Date] = @MaxDate OR [Date] = @MinDate))
    
--Insert new data
INSERT INTO [Data]
SELECT * FROM [UpdateTemp];
    
--Delete UpdateTemp table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[UpdateTemp];
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for you help everyone, you really saved my bacon -- much appreciated! :)